# Pausing Processing on Flink KeyedStream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink streaming application that need the ability to 'pause' and 'unpause' processing on a specific keyed stream. 'Processing' means just performing some simple anomaly detection on the stream.

The flow we are thinking about works like this:

Stream of Commands, either `ProcessCommand`, `PauseCommand`, or `ResumeCommand`, each with an `id` that is used to `KeyBy`.

`ProcessCommands` will check if the key is paused before being processed, and buffer if not.

`PauseCommands` will pause the processing of a key.

`ResumeCommands` will unpause the processing of a key and flush the buffer through.

Does this flow seem reasonable and, if so, would I be able to use something like the `split` operator to achieve?

Example stream, individual record timestamps ommitted:

`[{command: process, id: 1}, {command: pause, id: 1}, {command: process, id: 1}, {command: resume, id: 1}, {command: process, id: 1}]`

```
Flow:
=>
{command: process, id: 1} # Sent downstream for analysis
=> 
{command: pause, id: 1} # Starts the buffer for id 1
=>
{command: process, id: 1} # Buffered into another output stream
=> 
{command: resume, id: 1} # Turns off buffering, flushes [{command: process, id: 1}] downstream
=>
{command: process, id: 1} # Sent downstream for processing as the buffering has been toggled off
```

Comment: So, your actual stream (which contains records along with `id`) will receive the commands as a part of the record and the stream processing will be controlled using these commands right?

Comment: Yes, exactly right @shriyog. Each record has an `id` and a `command`.

Comment: What's the difference between `process` and `pause` commands? Can you please give an example showcasing the input command stream and expected behavior?

Comment: @shriyog, do those edits do a better job explaining? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using [**Flink's Window operator**](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/operators/windows.html). Firstly, create a `POJO` or `tuple` based stream by applying a `map` operation.

Then, as per your needs, you can use `keyBy` on that stream to get a `keyedStream`.

Now, by using a combination of time-based infinite `window`, a `trigger`, and a `window function`, you can achieve the switching behavior of your command stream.

Basically, you can use `windows` as your buffer, which after receiving a pause record, holds the process records until a resume record is received. You would be writing a custom trigger which evicts the window(a buffer) as per your scenario.

Following is a custom implementation of `Trigger` having `onElement()` overridden method.

```
/**
 * We trigger the window processing as per command inside the record. The
 * process records are buffered when a pause record is received and the
 * buffer is evicted once resume record is received. If no pause record is
 * received earlier, then for each process record the buffer is evicted.
 */
@Override
public TriggerResult onElement(Tuple2<Integer, String> element, long timestamp, Window window,
        TriggerContext context) throws Exception {
    if (element.f1.equals("pause")) {
        paused = true;
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    } else if (element.f1.equals("resume")) {
        paused = false;
        return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
    } else if (paused) // paused is a ValueState per keyed stream.
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
}
```

Check out the complete working example in this [github repository](https://github.com/shriyog/flink-starter/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/shriyog/flinkstarter/streamswitch)

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll implement this and then accept the answer!

Comment: All very clear - my only question is about the `transient` `paused` variable. It's just as reasonable to keep that in a `ValueState`, right?

Comment: Yup, that's the correct way actually. A managed keyed state can help us here https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state

Comment: Great, that's what I'm using! Thank you once again for all the help.

Comment: Expanding on this question, any idea how one would buffer some messages but let others through? So we would add a "process-passthrough" command to skip the buffering window and continue downstream.

Comment: Thinking about using a `split` stream and only windowing the `process` items, then join with the `process-passthrough` stream for downstream processing.

Comment: I think the passthrough records would behave in a similar fashion as process records since the window(containing 1 record) would be evicted on each record. But if you want the `process-passthrough` records to skip the entire window-evict step, `splitting` the stream is the best option.